# Adding a number to a marker in Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, python-imaging-library

I currently have markers displaying as below, but without the numbers that signify there is more than one item in that exact location.

I would like the markers to display as shown below:

[image]

I was able to in back-end group the items based on exact location and that is fine, but I can't seem to find a way to add the special number/count to show how many items are there without creating special images with numbers drawn in them.
Ideas on how this could be done?

One other direction if I can't doing it cleanly is use PIL to add the number to the image.  Still I don't think that is ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, what you want to do is inject HTML instead of images in the custom markers. It's essentially what you are doing but google allows you to [`OverlayViews`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays), even of HTML type. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCr2B/99/)

```
HTMLMarker.prototype.onAdd= function(){
    div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.className = "htmlMarker";
    div.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:30px;height:22px">'+ 'your number count'; //This HTML here is driven by your login to have numbers.
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
}
```

===[**UPDATE**]===

So, [I tried checking if I could add multiple overlays on the map](http://jsfiddle.net/BCr2B/124/). I could but they somehow ended up at the same location, and I tried multiple iterations but was not very successful in separating them out.

So, since you are essentially looking for numbering on markers, I looked around for other ways to solve this issue. I found this library on google maps, [markers with labels](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/examples/basic.html).

You can find a fiddle on how I [customized the markers here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vug7W/155/).

Comment: While this does work I can't seem to add more than one object.  For example if you add more than one object to the fiddle you just get a stack of images based on the first images location.

Comment: Can you share the fiddle code, let me have a look at what your code is trying to do.

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/BCr2B/113/ It could be I just don't get how your object works.

Comment: Updated my answer. This should probably be something that will solve your problem.